# how to make mfc application independent to visual studio 10

Tags: c++, mfc

I have made mfc application using vs10 and made a setup file also for my application .
I can not be able to use this application in a system where vs10 is not there. 
Please help .

Thanks in advance

Comment: If it fixes your problem, consider up-voting and "accept answer"

Answer (score 2):

You have to install Redistributable Package on that machine.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=5555

Alternatively, you can pack required dlls with your application.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the redistributable package of VS 2010 in your installation:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555

Answer (score 0):

Users will need the Visual C++ 2010 runtimes on their system, which are available through redistributable packages. They should be included with your VS install, but you can also download them separately here:

x86: http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=5555

x64: http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=14632

Answer (score 0):

You can use static linking of libraries to avoid the dependencies and avoid the need for installing the VC redistributable. There are two libraries required by your application: The runtime library and the MFC library. Static linking includes these libraries in your exe file.

In the project properties, for the release configuration, set "Runtime Library" to Multithreaded (/MT), and set "Use of MFC" to Use MFC in a Static Library.